# Behaviour of mobile app browsers with Google sessions and Account Chooser

Tags: android, ios, google-chrome, single-sign-on, google-oauth

Problem : Trying to create SSO between mobile app. and browser.

**What we have:**

We have an ionic mobile app. with "Login with Google" using OAuth 2.0 authentication. We have multiple inhouse apps that works on OAuth2 and SAML hence, we have SSO enabled for GSuite so that all apps work seamlessly with one login and password. Now when we hit the "Login with Google" button,

1. Opens to SSO login page in a browser app. We have SSO enabled
   hence we have set login_hint, which helps us in directly takes us to
   SSO login page.
2. User inputs useremail and password and it redirects to the
   redirect_uri post successful authentication with OAuth 2 code param.
3. The redirect_uri is done in a way that when the url is triggered,
   it redirect back to our android app again with OAuth 2 code param and
   then we extract the access_token and useremail from token and
   userinfo endpoints.
4. Basis the authorisation, dashboard shows the links to our internal
   apps. that works with Google SAML 2.0 or OAuth2 authentication.

**What is expected:**

When user hits any of the SAML/OAuth 2 link from mobile app. dashboard, we open that link in browser app. and it should get automatically logged in to that app. and take us to the landing page as we have already Google sessions set in step #a.

**Things deviating from expectations:**

- When we try to access the SAML/OAuth apps, it shows up the account chooser when there is a profile set in Chrome browser which lists all the accounts synced in device but not the one user have logged in with #b. It should show that account or directly login and show the landing page. Its not happening when we don't have a chrome profile set.
- The sessions in all the browser are killed automatically when we do following and hence asks for the credentials again.

  - close the browser tab(sometimes).
  - clear the browser from recent apps tray(most of the times)
  - restart the device(always)

Wanted to understand how and when the sessions are created and killed automatically in Google Chrome in mobile phones ?

Is there any where to keep the session intact ?
|Is there any way to bye-pass the account chooser showing the accounts synced with phone ?

**Update**

Able to figure out strange observation:
We kept SSO off so that Google Login screen comes into picture. With this everything is working fine. Sessions are not killed even if restart browser or phone irrespective of Android or iOS.

So the problem is in SSO that we have designed. Not able to figure out what is to be set in SAML XML that we post to Google's ACS URL.

Answer (score 5):

### 1. Wanted to understand how and when the sessions are created and killed automatically in Google Chrome in mobile phones?

I think Google Chrome acts in mobile phones the same way that it does in computers, so sessions are created and killed using the [HTML5 sessionStorage](https://code.google.com/archive/p/sessionstorage/),  user [configuration](https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/95314?hl=en&visit_id=1-636245258173125619-1005267871&rd=1) and device [policies](https://support.google.com/chromebook/answer/1331549):

> There are two types of [Web Storage](https://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_webstorage.asp) so far, and these are the
>   localStorage, and the sessionStorage. The main difference is that the
>   [localStorage](https://www.w3.org/TR/webstorage/#the-localstorage-attribute) persists over different tabs or windows, and even if we
>   close the browser, accordingly with the domain security policy and
>   user choices about quota limit.

Also, it's important to know [how Chrome saves and syncs passwords](https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/95606?visit_id=1-636245258173125619-1005267871&p=settings_password&rd=1):

> **How Chrome saves and syncs passwords (in computer and Android devices)** depends on whether you want to store
>   and use them across devices. When synced, passwords can be utilized on
>   Chrome on all your devices, and across some apps on your Android
>   device.
>
> Your passwords are saved to your Google Account if either of the
>   following are true:
>
> - You're signed in to Chrome and are syncing passwords
> - You're using
>     Smart Lock for Passwords on Android
>
> Otherwise, your passwords are only stored on Chrome on your computer or Android device.
>
> **How Chrome saves and syncs passwords (in iPhone and iPad devices)** depends on whether you want to store and use them across devices.
>
> Your passwords are saved to your Google Account if you're signed in to
>   Chrome and are syncing passwords.
>
> Otherwise, your passwords are only stored on Chrome on your iPhone or
>   iPad.

---

### **2. Is there any way to keep the session intact ?**

I'm not skilled/interested in iOs or HTML5 development, but I tried something similar for Android and a legacy Google Apps domain when Google launched [Smart Lock for Passwords on Android](https://developers.google.com/identity/smartlock-passwords/android/):

> Programmatically save and retrieve credentials, and automatically sign
>   users in across devices and websites in Chrome.

**Note:** SSL is required on your server to [Enable automatic sign-in across apps and websites](https://developers.google.com/identity/smartlock-passwords/android/associate-apps-and-sites)

The Smart Lock for Passwords and [Connected Accounts API](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/auth/api/credentials/package-summary) facilitates the saving and retrieval of credentials for your app and associated site

You can [Handle multiple saved credentials](https://developers.google.com/identity/smartlock-passwords/android/retrieve-credentials#handle_multiple_saved_credentials) and [manually Delete stored credentials](https://developers.google.com/identity/smartlock-passwords/android/delete-credentials)

> When user input is required to select a credential, the
>   getStatusCode() method returns RESOLUTION_REQUIRED. In this case, call
>   the status object's startResolutionForResult() method to prompt the
>   user to choose an account. Then, retrieve the user's chosen
>   credentials from the activity's onActivityResult() method by passing
>   Credential.EXTRA_KEY to the getParcelableExtra() method.

And [Sign In Using ID Tokens](https://developers.google.com/identity/smartlock-passwords/android/idtoken-auth) available when a Credential object's user ID matches the user ID of a Google account that is signed in on the device.

How to [implement it](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30765965/1009132) and useful scenarios to [test](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34761243/1009132) and [check](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34862048/1009132) it in related SO answers.

---

### **3. Is there any way to bye-pass the account chooser showing the accounts synced with phone ?**

[Use Google Sign-In with IT Apps](https://developers.google.com/identity/work/it-apps)

> Whitelist the application so that your users will not see a
>   confirmation screen when they sign in. This step, combined with the
>   next steps (*point 4: pass Google for Work domain of the account to the auth server, so only accounts in that domain are displayed during sign-in*), ensures that users of your IT application can
>   automatically sign in. To whitelist your app:
>
> - Open the [G Suite Admin Console](https://admin.google.com/).
> - Click the Security icon, then click Show More > Advanced Settings > Manage API client access.

[image]
[image]
[image]

> - Enter the OAuth client ID you registered for the application. A client ID is normally a string of letters and numbers followed by
>     .apps.googleusercontent.com.
> - In the API Scopes field, type the following string: https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.me,https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email
> - If your app needs to request additional scopes to access Google APIs, specify them here.
> - Click Authorize. The whitelisting will take effect in about 30 minutes.
>
> **Note:** The whitelisting will not work if the app starts the OAuth/Open ID Connect flow and includes the parameters **offline** or
>   **prompt**. These parameters are generally not needed for IT apps.

[Force/bypass google account chooser in OAuth2 authorization URLs](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14393492/1009132)

> The following parameter is supported in OAuth2 authorization URLs: **prompt**
>
> Currently it can have values '`none`', '`select_account`', and '`consent`'.
>
> **none**: Will cause Google not to show any UI, and therefore fail if the user
>   needs to login, or select an account in case of multi-login, or
>   consent if first approval. It can be run in an invisible i-frame to
>   obtain a token from previously authorised users before you decide, for
>   instance, to render an authorization button.
>
> **consent**: Will force the approval page to be displayed even if the user
>   has previously authorised your application. May be useful in a few
>   corner cases, for instance, if you lost the refresh_token for the user,
>   as Google only issues refresh_tokens on explicit consent action.
>
> **select_account**: Will cause the account selector to display, even if
>   there's a single logged-in user, just as you asked.
>
> **select_account can be combined with consent**, as in: `prompt=select_account+consent`

[using authorisation via the JS client library](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13379472/1009132)

> You are not getting the multi-user selection screen because of the
>   following parameter: authuser=0 This automatically selects the first
>   account you are signed in with (authuser=1 would choose the second
>   etc.).

---

### **4. Update: With SSO off all is working fine...sessions are not killed...**

[SAML-based Federated SSO](https://support.google.com/a/answer/6087519)

[Here's how to set up Single Sign-On (SSO) via SAML for the Slack® application](https://support.google.com/a/answer/6357481).

> Using Security Assertion Markup Language (SAML), your users can use
>   their Google Cloud credentials to sign in to enterprise-cloud
>   applications.
>
> As an administrator, you have to configure a few things to make it work,
>   including:
>
> - Set up the selected application as a SAML service provider (SP).
> - Set up G Suite as a SAML identity provider (IdP).
> - Enter application-specific service provider details in Google Admin console.
> - Turn on single sign-on (SSO) for the application.
> - Verify that the SSO is working.

[Configure the pre-integrated cloud applications or your own SAML app](https://support.google.com/a/answer/6087519?hl=en)

> [Sign in](https://admin.google.com/). Click Apps > SAML apps. Select
>   the *Add a service/App to your domain* and setup:

[image]

[Turn on SSO to your new SAML app](https://support.google.com/a/answer/6087519?hl=en):

> Sign in to your [Admin console](https://admin.google.com/). Go to
>   *Apps > SAML apps*.
>
> Select the app. At the top of the grey box, click *More Settings* and
>   choose:
>
> - On for everyone to turn on the service for all users (click again to confirm).
> - Off to turn off the service for all users (click again to confirm).
> - On for some organisations to change the setting only for some users.

[image]
[image]
[image]

[Use Google Sign-In with IT Apps](https://developers.google.com/identity/work/it-apps)

> The following is a checklist of steps to take when using Google
>   Sign-In with work accounts for a custom-developed IT application. If
>   you are developing a mobile app, refer to the [best practices for
>   mobile](https://developers.google.com/identity/work/it-mobile-apps) as well.
>
> If your app knows the Google for Work domain of the account, you
>   should pass that domain to the auth server so only accounts in that
>   domain are displayed during sign-in. On Android, this is done with the
>   [setHostedDomain](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/auth/api/signin/GoogleSignInOptions.Builder#setHostedDomain(java.lang.String))
>   builder method, and on iOS, this is done with the
>   [hostedDomain](https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/ios/api/interface_g_i_d_sign_in#a6d85d14588e8bf21a4fcf63e869e3be3) property.
>
> This is also done using the `hd` parameter with the REST endpoint, and
>   the hosted_domain parameter with the JavaScript API.

---

### **5. What ... to set in SAML XML that we post to Google's ACS URL.**

[Configuring Provider Metadata for SAML Integration](https://documentation.commvault.com/commvault/v11/article?p=products/web_console/external_authentication/t_wcnsl_admin_saml_provider_metadata.htm)

> SAML metadata is used to share configuration information between the
>   Identity Provider (IdP) and the Service Provider (SP). Metadata for
>   both the IdP and the SP is defined in an XML file:
>
> The IdP metadata XML file contains the IdP certificate, the entity ID,
>   the redirect URL, and the post URL, for example,
>   [saml_idp_metadata.xml](https://documentation.commvault.com/commvault/v11/others/products/web_console/external_authentication/saml_idp_metadata.xml).

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
  <md:EntityDescriptor xmlns:md="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:metadata" xmlns:ds="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#" entityID="https://test.my.company.com" validUntil="2024-08-13T07:37:40.675Z">
    <md:IDPSSODescriptor WantAuthnRequestsSigned="false" protocolSupportEnumeration="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:protocol">
      <md:KeyDescriptor use="signing">
        <ds:KeyInfo>
          <ds:X509Data>
            <ds:X509Certificate>encoded_certificate</ds:X509Certificate>
          </ds:X509Data>
        </ds:KeyInfo>
      </md:KeyDescriptor>
    <md:NameIDFormat>urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:1.1:nameid-format:unspecified</md:NameIDFormat>
    <md:SingleSignOnService Binding="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:bindings:HTTP-POST" Location="https://https://test.my.company.com/idp/endpoint/HttpPost"/>
    <md:SingleSignOnService Binding="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:bindings:HTTP-Redirect" Location="https://test.my.company.com/idp/endpoint/HttpRedirect"/>
  </md:IDPSSODescriptor>
</md:EntityDescriptor>
```

> The SP metadata XML file contains the SP certificate, the entity ID,
>   and the Assertion Consumer Service URL (ACS URL), for example,
>   [saml_sp_metadata.xml](https://documentation.commvault.com/commvault/v11/others/products/web_console/external_authentication/saml_sp_metadata.xml).

```
<EntityDescriptor xmlns:md="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:metadata" entityID="http://client.mydomain.com:80/webconsole">
  <SPSSODescriptor WantAssertionsSigned="true" protocolSupportEnumeration="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:protocol">
    <AssertionConsumerService Binding="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:bindings:HTTP-POST" Location="http://client.mydomain.com:80/webconsole/samlAcsCallback.do" isDefault="true"/>
    <KeyDescriptor>
      <ds:KeyInfo xmlns:ds="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#">
        <ds:X509Data>
          <ds:X509Certificate>encoded_certificate</ds:X509Certificate>
        </ds:X509Data>
      </ds:KeyInfo>
    </KeyDescriptor>
    <NameIDFormat>urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:nameid-format:entity</NameIDFormat>
  </SPSSODescriptor>
</EntityDescriptor>
```

> Before using SAML to log on to the Web Console, metadata from the IdP
>   must be uploaded and metadata from the SP must be generated. After the
>   SP metadata is generated, it must be shared with the IdP. Contact the
>   IdP for instructions on sharing the SP metadata.
>
> Create an Identity Provider (IdP) metadata XML file using the SAML
>   protocol. For SAML metadata specifications, go to the [Oasis
>   website](https://www.oasis-open.org/), [Metadata for the OASIS
>   Security Assertion Markup Language (SAML)
>   V2.0](https://docs.oasis-open.org/security/saml/v2.0/saml-metadata-2.0-os.pdf).
>
> Create a keystore file. For information on keystore files, see
>   [Creating Certificates for SAML
>   Integration](https://documentation.commvault.com/commvault/v11/article?p=products/web_console/external_authentication/t_wcnsl_admin_saml_certificates.htm).
>
> For more information on the keytool utility, go to the [Oracle
>   Documentation website](http://docs.oracle.com/en/), [keytool - Key and
>   Certificate Management
>   Tool](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/tools/windows/keytool.html).

[SAML service provider URLs](https://support.google.com/a/answer/6301827?hl=en)

> To set up G Suite as SAML identity provider (IdP), you need to enter
>   the SAML service provider URLs for each of the individual
>   pre-configured cloud applications you plan to set up.
>
> [Links](https://support.google.com/a/answer/6301827?hl=en) for Entity
>   ID, ACS URL, and Start URL values for each of the pre-configured cloud
>   apps.

---

### **6. Troubleshooting Single Sign-On (SSO)**

> [This document](https://support.google.com/a/answer/2463723?hl=en)
>   provides steps to resolve common error messages encountered during the
>   integration or use of [SAML-based Single Sign-On
>   (SSO)](https://support.google.com/a/answer/60224) with G Suite when
>   Google is the service provider (SP).

Comment: Thanks alot for help :). Could you please check the update section if you have idea about it ?

Comment: You are welcome, I'll update my answer this night, I'm experimenting with preconfigured slack app and custom one. Check [this link](https://documentation.commvault.com/commvault/v11/article?p=products/web_console/external_authentication/t_wcnsl_admin_saml_provider_metadata.htm) and [g suite help](https://support.google.com/a/answer/6087519?hl=en). Also check security, advanced settings, all it's ok, and try using [a preconfigured app like slack](https://support.google.com/a/answer/6357481?hl=en). Now is football time :)